# Looping Futures Exception. How to fix the cause

Tags: meteor

I'm working through the Discover Meteor book and after implementing the 'Errors' chapter, a typo caused an error an now the app is loop with the exception presented below.

My question is, how do I fix it or reset (I've tried 'meteor reset' but the exception loop persists)

```
W20140711-10:21:00.387(2)? (STDERR) 
W20140711-10:21:00.388(2)? (STDERR) /Users/mwho/.meteor/tools/858c88b520/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20140711-10:21:00.390(2)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20140711-10:21:00.391(2)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20140711-10:21:00.479(2)? (STDERR) Error: allow: Invalid key: remote
W20140711-10:21:00.480(2)? (STDERR)     at packages/mongo-livedata/collection.js:575
W20140711-10:21:00.492(2)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20140711-10:21:00.493(2)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:105)
W20140711-10:21:00.494(2)? (STDERR)     at addValidator (packages/mongo-livedata/collection.js:573)
W20140711-10:21:00.496(2)? (STDERR)     at Meteor.Collection.allow (packages/mongo-livedata/collection.js:613)
W20140711-10:21:00.496(2)? (STDERR)     at app/collections/posts.js:3:7
W20140711-10:21:00.497(2)? (STDERR)     at app/collections/posts.js:52:3
W20140711-10:21:00.498(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/mwho/microsope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:155:10
W20140711-10:21:00.500(2)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20140711-10:21:00.500(2)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/mwho/.meteor/tools/858c88b520/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
=> Exited with code: 8
```

Posts.js

```
Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts');

Posts.allow({
    update: ownsDocument,
    remote: ownsDocument
});

Posts.deny({
    update: function( userId, post, fieldNames ) {
        // may only edit the following two fields:
        return (_.without(fieldNames, 'url', 'title').length > 0);
    }
});

    Meteor.methods({
        post: function(postAttributes) {
            var user = Meteor.user(),
                postWithSameLink = Posts.findOne({
                    url: postAttributes.url
                });
            // ensure the user is logged in
            if (!user) throw new Meteor.Error(401, "You need to login to post new stories");
            // ensure the post has a title
            if (!postAttributes.title) throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'Please fill in a headline');
            // check that there are no previous posts with the same link
            if (postAttributes.url && postWithSameLink) {
                throw new Meteor.Error(302,
                    'This link has already been posted', postWithSameLink._id);
            }
            // pick out the whitelisted keys
            var post = _.extend(_.pick(postAttributes, 'url', 'title', 'message'), {
                title: postAttributes.title + (this.isSimulation ? '(client)' : '(server)'),
                userId: user._id,
                author: user.username,
                submitted: new Date().getTime()
            });
            //
            // wait 5 seconds
            if ( ! this.isSimulation ) {
              var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
              var future = new Future();
              Meteor.setTimeout( function() {
                future.return();
              }, 5*1000);
              future.wait();
            }
            var postId = Posts.insert(post);
            return postId;
        }
    });
```

Comment: please show us contents of `collections/posts.js`

Comment: Updated the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a typo in your code.

```
Posts.allow({
    update: ownsDocument,
    remote: ownsDocument
});
```

should be changed as

```
Posts.allow({
    update: ownsDocument,
    remove: ownsDocument
});
```